# Multiple preserveAspectRatio in svg?

Tags: svg

I'm looking to have an svg fill a particular space in my layout, so `preserveAspectRatio="none"` seems like a good first approach.

However, within the svg, there is a mask that I do *not* want to stretch / warp. Rather, it should occupy 100% the width, with the height scaling according to its ratio. The two images illustrate the mask's behaviour when the parent svg is in either landscape or portrait. (Note: the grey in the image is the rest of the `<svg>`, which should stretch to fit)

Can the mask have its own aspectRatio settings? Is there a better way to achieve this? Or, is it even possible?

[image: example of mask when filling landscape area]
[image: example of the mask when in a portrait viewport]

```

```
<!-- this should scale according to its bounding parent -->
<svg class="fix" viewbox="0 0 2880 1620" preserveAspectRatio="none..?">

  <!-- this should scale according to some intrinsic ratio -->
  <mask id="mask" 
        maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" 
        maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <rect fill="white" x="0" y="0" width="2880" height="1620" /> 
    <path fill="black" d="M57.59,60h409c344.17,.... ...."/>
  </mask>

  <rect mask="url(#mask)" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />

</svg>
```

```

edit: using `mask-image` instead of just `mask` seems possible (as it has additional positioning options), but this does not seem to work with svg elements.

Comment: No to your question. Anything inside the SVG will be affected by the `preserveAspectRatio`.  Also, why are you using `preserveAspectRatio="none"`? The behaviour you illustrate in your mockups is the behaviour of the default `preserveAspectRatio` (`"xMidYMid meet"`).

Comment: Hey Paul - yeah I figured as much, thanks. I'm using preserveAspectRatio=none because I wish the rest of the svg to scale/stretch within an arbitrary space; however the mask within should not. As an aside, I've seen <symbol> with multiple <svg>s within that actually allow this behavior (i.e. different aspectRatios), but wasn't able to solve for a mask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to have the rectangle and mask fill the page. Just extend the `<rect>` and `<mask>` past the boundaries of the SVG in all directions.  Root `<svg>` elements have `overflow: visible` by default, so the extended rect will fill SVGs parent container - as long as you extend far enough of course.

```
<rect mask="url(#mask)" x="-1000%" y="-1000%" width="3000%" height="3000%" />
```

I've used 1000% here, but you can adjust that if you need more or less (than 10x).

And note that we are just using the standard default SVG `preserveAspectRatio`. So we still get the automatic centerinng and scaling of the SVG.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

svg {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 2880 1620">

  <!-- this should scale according to some intrinsic ratio -->
  <mask id="mask" 
        maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" 
        maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        x="-1000%" y="-1000%" width="3000%" height="3000%">
    <rect fill="white" x="-1000%" y="-1000%" width="3000%" height="3000%" /> 
    <circle cx="1440" cy="810" r="400" fill="black"/>
  </mask>

  <rect mask="url(#mask)" x="-1000%" y="-1000%" width="3000%" height="3000%" />

</svg>
```

[Demo in fiddle format](https://jsfiddle.net/pfzjke34/)

Comment: ah, interesting. that's a solution i never thought of, cheers!